# Can you play Magic: Duels 2HG with 1P/2P vs. AI/AI?

Tags: magic-duels

I have a cousin who wants to play 2HG with me but he's downloading Duels for the first time and obviously doesn't have any boosters opened yet, just the starter box, and we don't want to get slaughtered by playing against real players just yet.

Will 2HG in Magic Duels allow me to play with my cousin over Xbox Live against two bots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://magic.wizards.com/content/magic-duels-faq) says that you can play with any mix of human and AI players.  It does specifically mention console support.

> ...you'll then face off against another randomly selected human/AI or AI/AI team. For PC and console players you can also be randomly paired against human/human teams.

Invite your cousin to your game, hopefully you will be on the same team.  If you are put on opposite teams instead:

> Q: When I try to play Two-Headed Giant with a friend, they're put on the opposite team. What should I do?
>
> A: This is a known issue that we are researching. For the time being, we recommend conceding your Two-Headed Giant game and trying to create a new match.